# How can i make this program faster(more efficient)?

Tags: python

I have this code that creates unique passwords using the first letter of each word from the file.Before each password is created(written to a file) it is compared to all passwords that are currently in the file, so if the file has 50,000 passwords before a another is written it has to scan through all 50k. 
A user can input any amount of passwords needed but the bigger the number the longer it takes 100k will take a long time how can i optimize this to make the program run faster ? The password generation is not included code

```
for mainLoop in range(passnum):

      user  = 0
      newpass = generatePassword() # New password generated each iteration of loop
      storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","a")
      print ("PASSWORD GENERATED ")

      #Checks if file is empty if True write first password
      fileEmpty = os.stat("MnemPass.txt").st_size == 0
      if fileEmpty == True:
          storePass.write(newpass)
          storePass.write("\n")
          storePass.close()
          print ("FIRST PASSWORD WRITTEN")

      #IF file is not empty Read line by line and compare each with new password generated returns boolean value
      elif  fileEmpty == False:
            storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","r")
            with open("MnemPass.txt") as f:
                fileData = f.read().splitlines()
                linelength = len(fileData).__int__()
                filemax = linelength
                num = linelength    #Number used to cycle through array set to size of list
                #print(linelength+10)

                for iterate in range(linelength):
                    num = num - 1 #Number decreases each pass
                    #print num
                    if fileData[num] != newpass: # The last element in the array is checked first decrementing each pass
                       go = True

                    if fileData[num]==newpass: #changed
                        print ("match found: PASSWORD : "+fileData[num])
                        passMatch = open("Matchpassword.txt","a")
                        passMatch.write(newpass)
                        passMatch.write("\n")
                        passMatch.close()
                        go = False
                        break

                    #places new password once it does not match and all elements prev passwords are compared
                    if go == True and num == 0:
                      storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","a")
                      storePass.write(newpass)
                      storePass.write("\n")
                      storePass.close()
                      print ("NEW WRITTEN")



            if linelength == filemax:

                num = num -1
```

*new Code - i used the set function *

```
 passnum = (input("How many passwords do you need :"))
  sTime = datetime.now()
```

storePass = open ("MnemPass.txt","a") # file open out of loop to increase speed
  fileEmpty = os.stat("MnemPass.txt").st_size == 0

new_passwords = set()
  CurrentPasswords = set()

if fileEmpty == True:
     while len(new_passwords)!= passnum:  #will cause problems if dictionary cannot create amount needed
           new_passwords.add(generatePassword())

```
 for pw in new_passwords:
       storePass.write(pw + "\n")
```

else:
       new_passwords =  set(line.strip() for line in open ("MnemPass.txt"))
       for num in range(passnum):
           temp = generatePassword()

`if temp not in new_passwords:
          CurrentPasswords.add(temp)
       else:
           "match found"`

for pw2 in CurrentPasswords:
           storePass.write(pw2 + "\n")

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, it may be better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: yea its working ok ill do that

Comment: the running time might depend on how efficient your `generatePassword()` method is too

Comment: AFAIK you are only storing the passwords in the file and always reading them and rewriting them at each iteration. It would be much simpler to just have a dictionary storing the password then checking if the password was already there would be a very fast operation and you can save the dictionary contents to file only at the end. This should be way more efficient than what you are doing now.

Comment: @PruthviRaj that function use a array dictionary to append a letter randomly it uses one loop and then joins the array to string and returns i didn't figure that could factor in to the poor execution time of the program

Comment: @Bakuriu its reading them not re-writing, could you give an example of that is it a python function that i could use ?

Answer (score 1):

You can considerably reduce runtime by loading the file once and then appending each new password to it rather than open file in loop and check line by line,Here I am using `uuid` in `generatePassword()` to generate a random string of length between 3 and 10

**Your code:**

```
def func(passnum):
    import os,uuid,random
    def generatePassword():
        return str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')[0:random.randint(3,10)]
    for mainLoop in range(passnum):

          user  = 0
          newpass = generatePassword() # New password generated each iteration of loop
          storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","a")
          print ("PASSWORD GENERATED ")

          #Checks if file is empty if True write first password
          fileEmpty = os.stat("MnemPass.txt").st_size == 0
          if fileEmpty == True:
              storePass.write(newpass)
              storePass.write("\n")
              storePass.close()
              print ("FIRST PASSWORD WRITTEN")

          #IF file is not empty Read line by line and compare each with new password generated returns boolean value
          elif  fileEmpty == False:
                storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","r")
                with open("MnemPass.txt") as f:
                    fileData = f.read().splitlines()
                    linelength = len(fileData).__int__()
                    filemax = linelength
                    num = linelength    #Number used to cycle through array set to size of list
                    #print(linelength+10)

                    for iterate in range(linelength):
                        num = num - 1 #Number decreases each pass
                        #print num
                        if fileData[num] != newpass: # The last element in the array is checked first decrementing each pass
                           go = True

                        if fileData[num]==newpass: #changed
                            print ("match found: PASSWORD : "+fileData[num])
                            passMatch = open("Matchpassword.txt","a")
                            passMatch.write(newpass)
                            passMatch.write("\n")
                            passMatch.close()
                            go = False
                            break

                        #places new password once it does not match and all elements prev passwords are compared
                        if go == True and num == 0:
                          storePass = open("MnemPass.txt","a")
                          storePass.write(newpass)
                          storePass.write("\n")
                          storePass.close()
                          print ("NEW WRITTEN")



                if linelength == filemax:

                    num = num -1
```

I slightly modified it to load the file at starting itself and append for every new password, notice that we don't need inner for loop anymore, the code becomes:

```
def func2(passnum):
    import uuid
    import os, random
    linelength = 0
    fileData = []
    if os.path.isfile('MnemPass.txt'):
        f = open("MnemPass.txt", "r")
        fileData += f.read().splitlines()
        linelength = len(fileData).__int__()
        f.close()

    def generatePassword():
        return str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')[0:random.randint(3,10)]

    for mainLoop in range(passnum):

        user = 0
        newpass = generatePassword()  # New password generated each iteration of loop
        storePass = open("MnemPass.txt", "a")
        print ("PASSWORD GENERATED ")

        # Checks if file is empty if True write first password
        fileEmpty = os.stat("MnemPass.txt").st_size == 0
        if fileEmpty == True:
            storePass.write(newpass)
            storePass.write("\n")
            storePass.close()
            print ("FIRST PASSWORD WRITTEN")

        # IF file is not empty Read line by line and compare each with new password generated returns boolean value
        elif fileEmpty == False:
            storePass = open("MnemPass.txt", "r")
            filemax = linelength
            num = linelength  # Number used to cycle through array set to size of list
            # print(linelength+10)

            if newpass in fileData:
                    print ("match found: PASSWORD : " , fileData.index(newpass))
                    passMatch = open("Matchpassword.txt", "a")
                    passMatch.write(newpass)
                    passMatch.write("\n")
                    passMatch.close()
            else:
                    linelength += 1
                    fileData.append(newpass)
                    storePass = open("MnemPass.txt", "a")
                    storePass.write(newpass)
                    storePass.write("\n")
                    storePass.close()
                    print ("NEW WRITTEN")
            if linelength == filemax:
                num = num - 1
```

**Profile for your code:**

[image]

**Profile for modified code:**

[image]

As you can see the runtime has reduced from `45secs` to `27secs` ! :)

**NOTE:**

I ran the tests for 10000 passwords and deleted the generated files for next pass :)

Comment: i used the set function and sped up the program a ton thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your code runs in a loop as you present here:
Checking the whole file on every loop iteration is not very efficient.
It is much more efficient to keep a set of created passwords and check if a new password is already in the set before adding it.
Also in this case you should only open the file once outside the main for loop and close it afterwards.

In the case that your program adds only one password and then returns, it is better to add each new password in a way that your file remains sorted. This way you can use binary search to search if a password already exists.

Comment: In keeping a set do you mean generating a group of passwords before writing to the file then checking? I will still need to ensure that the list has no duplicates. I know the constant opening and closing of files within the loop may slow down the program i will try to limit that

Comment: @Doug_Brown What he means is: `new_passwords = set(); while True: new_passwords.add(generatePassword())` `set`s never contain duplicates, so you simply have to stop the loop when you have enough elements. At that point: `for pw in new_passwords: outfile.write(pw)` or something like that.

Comment: @Bakuriu  and Cantfindname i used set and got it to work using the set function it is really quick i opened the file outside and the execution time decreased significantly